# Rider debug visualizer for datatable like in visual studio as a table

Tags: c#, datatable, rider, visualizer

I looked and looked and could not find an answer to this.  With Rider, when debugging, how can you display a datatable as a table like in Visual Studio? Like in VS when you hover over a datatable, it displays it as a table with all columns and rows.

[datatable visualizer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBM6Y.png)

Comment: It seems like this feature simply is not available in Rider. There is a task to add it, however for a few years it has not been resolved: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-9738

Comment: I can't believe it's not a feature.  That's pretty much a show stopper for me when working with older projects that use ado.net. It's so used in VS.

Answer (score 1):

EAP 2024.1 has added something that JustDoesThis:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/2024.1/Visualize_data_structures.html